# Auto Login for test

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a method to test , I have tried to give authorization using @WITHMOCKUSER and also manually by creating a method that takes in username and password  and gives it Authentication.
Method I want to test looks like this

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')")
    @RequestMapping("/bookDetail")
    public String bookDetail(
            @PathParam("id") Long id, Model model, Principal principal
    ) {.....
```

when I used this auto login method on my test

```
@Override
    public void autologin(String username, String password) throws AuthenticationException {


        UserDetails userDetails;
        try {
            userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());

            authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("invalid username or password");
        }
    }
}
```

on this test

```
@Test 
    public void checkBookDetail() throws Exception {
        securityService.autologin("V", "A");

        Book book = new Book();
        book.setId(1L);
```

I get error

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: invalid username or password
```

and when I  use @WithMockUser

```
 @Test
        @WithMockUser(username = "V", authorities = {"USER"})
        public void checkBookDetail() throws Exception {

            Book book = new Book();
            book.setId(1L);
            expect(bookService.findOne(anyLong())).andReturn(book);
            replay(bookService);
```

I get error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select user0_.id as id1_9_, user0_.email as email2_9_, user0_.enabled as enabled3_9_, user0_.first_name as first_na4_9_, user0_.last_name as last_nam5_9_, user0_.password as password6_9_, user0_.phone as phone7_9_, user0_.username as username8_9_ from user user0_ where user0_.username=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
```

Mean while in my sql data
I have

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES
  (1, 'admin@yahoo.com', 'TRUE', NULL, NULL, '$2a$12$LtbYtEzOBdnsiD/E9Wtj2OZz80wXDrKDMacktYr8pq3j0X6HO75Fm', NULL, 'admin'),
  (2, 'valentineezugu@yahoo.com', 'TRUE', 'Valentine', 'Ezugu', '$2a$12$LtbYtEzOBdnsiD/E9Wtj2Oj7SuEU4Z0YOHffjdDm2t01lMnQLyeCe', NULL, 'V'),
  (3, 'egbusonltd@yahoo.com', 'TRUE', NULL, NULL, '$2a$12$LtbYtEzOBdnsiD/E9Wtj2OsFAal5Zn4UPZpYT22PorhapAGnanfWq', NULL, 'ema');

INSERT INTO password_reset_token VALUES (1, '2017-10-01 16:27:48', '59bdd703-c3e4-4a59-b0b8-cbc936f47fbf', 3);

INSERT INTO role VALUES (0, 'ADMIN', 0), (1, 'USER', 1);

INSERT INTO shopping_cart VALUES (1, NULL, 2), (2, NULL, 3);

INSERT INTO user_role VALUES (1, 0, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3);
```

So I don't really understand why it doesn't work and what I can do to work around it? Thanks in advance

security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/image/**",
            "/",
            "/newUser",
            "/ForgetPassword",
            "/login",
            "/fonts/**",
            "/bookshelf",
            "/hours",
            "faq",
            "/SearchByCategory"
    };

    @Autowired
    private SecurityUtility securityUtility;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return securityUtility.passwordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().disable().cors().disable().
                authorizeRequests().and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
                .and()
                .rememberMe();
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {

        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        javaMailSender.setProtocol("SMTP");
        javaMailSender.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        javaMailSender.setPort(25);

        return javaMailSender;
    }

}
```